# eclipse JavaFX css resource not found

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx

I'm having a problem with stylesheets for `JavaFX` GUI.
My stylesheet won't load and I get this error:

```
com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "file:images\stylesheet.css" not found.
```

I tried putting the stylesheet.css in the same folder as the images. The images are no problem, but the stylesheet is not found.

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("images\\stylesheet.css");
```

I also tried this:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("file:images\\stylesheet.css");
```

and:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("file:///images/stylesheet.css");
```

I also tried different folders, like the one where the `.java` file is in.

Nothing seems to work. It's like `Eclipse` doesn't recognise stylesheets.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that java's `com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager` works with URLs, but it doesn't do a great job of converting File.toString() to a url, so you have to pass it a String that has already been converted to a file, to a URL, and back to a String. So when it parses the string as a URL, it doesn't choke on the space character.

This works:

```
String fontSheet = fileToStylesheetString( new File ("location") );

if ( fontSheet == null ) {
    //Do Whatever you want with logging/errors/etc.
} else {
    scene.getStylesheets().add( fontSheet );
}

public String fileToStylesheetString ( File stylesheetFile ) {
    try {
        return stylesheetFile.toURI().toURL().toString();
    } catch ( MalformedURLException e ) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using pretty much the same solution as by the previous answer, except for one extension, the `toString()` call:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("cssfile.css").toString());
```

In case the file that calls the above command is NOT in the same pacakge/directory as the css-file, add a relative path, i.e. `"images/cssfile.css"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `getClass().getResource("/images/stylesheet.css");`

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(
  getClass().getResource("/images/stylesheet.css")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Images in JavaFX internally implement the loading of resources from the class loader, but unfortunately this is not true for the stylesheets. So if you say :

```
new Image("/Images/background.png");
```

it gets transformed to :

```
new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Images/background.png");
```

but it doesn't happen in the case of `getStylesheets().add()`. So in order to run it you need to add a classloader yourself :

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(
      getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images\\stylesheet.css"));
```

**Note:** *The path here depends on the location of the css file.*